# Is there an x86 intrinsic that generates the AVX512 broadcast operation from a 32 bit floating point value in memory to a 512 bit register?

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx512

The instruction exists (`vbroadcastss zmm/m32`) but there seems to be no intrinsic to generate it.

I can code it as

```
static inline  __m512 mybroadcast(float *x) {
    __m512 v;
    asm inline ( "vbroadcastss %1,%0 "
                 : "=v" (v)
                 : "m" (*x)
                 );
    return v;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without inline asm?

Comment: you forgot to specify in which language in tags

Comment: It would depend entirely on the compiler ... but I suspect "No: you've already got the best solution you're likely to find".

Comment: @FoggyDay I'm thinking of the standard intel intrinsics.

Comment: It looks as if it doesn't exist: `test.c:5: Error: no such instruction: 'vpbroadcastss %zmm0,-64(%rsp)'`

Comment: Change it to `vbroadcastss` and it says `test.c:5: Error: operand size mismatch for 'vbroadcastss'`

Comment: @JL2210: yup, it's a typo and the `x` operand should be `"m"(*x)` to tell the compiler you want the *float* in memory, not a pointer in memory.  Or maybe better, `"xm"(*x)` might let the compiler give it to you in an XMM register instead of memory in case that was convenient; unlike AVX1, the AVX2 and AVX512 versions of `vbroadcastss` work as a reg-reg shuffle as well as a load.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast.  Anyway, that's still worse than an intrinsic because it defeats constant-propagation optimization among other things.

Comment: @JL2210: Just for fun I fixed the code in the question in case anyone's curious :P

Comment: @PeterCordes You shouldn't make sweeping edits like this.

Comment: @JL2210: Why not?  It's asking the exact same question better, without errors in the example.  I'm not going to start an edit war, but I'd recommend that Steve roll back to my edit.  I don't see that it's changing the intent in any way, and the original being totally broken was a distraction.  As a gold badge holder in several relevant tags (`[gcc]`, `[x86]`, `[c]`, etc.), I think improving questions to clearly ask what the OP clearly intended is a Good Thing when I understand the topic well enough to make edits like this.

Comment: @JL2210: After your edit, it still won't compile with just `gcc -march=skylake-avx512`.  The inline asm uses intel-syntax.  That comment was important; you'll still get your operand size mismatch error.  I also included links to the asm manual to justify the question as not being "lack of research effort" - usually you can find intrinsics for instructions in the asm manual entry.  And more details about why inline asm was sub-optimal because at least one commenter thought asm might already be optimal!  Anyway, the OP can choose between my edit or yours with a rollback.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed the operand order.

Comment: Why do you assume the OP wanted AT&T syntax instead of Intel syntax?  Both are technically valid choices.  (Although AT&T is usually standard).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `_mm512_set1_ps` is what you want.

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm512_set1_ps&expand=5236,4980

Comment: @SteveLinton: if you search for `broadcast` in that same intrinsics guide, `_mm_set1` intrinsics show up in the results (buried under a ton of AVX512 masked, unmaked, etc. stuff).  But if you control-f search within page for `float`, you find them quickly along with AVX1 `_mm256_broadcast_ss`.  (But there's no AVX512 version of that intrinsic.)